# Turn MS CRM country and state fields into drop down lists

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

By default, country and state/province fields in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 are plain textboxes.

I want them to be dropdowns instead, with the state dropdown being updated based on the selection in the country dropdown.  However, I don’t want to have to come up with states and provinces for every country in the world so any unconfigured ones should just show the normal text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trudging through many various solutions we didn't find anything that worked the way we wanted so we created a new solution.

We created a [countries_and_states.js](https://raw.github.com/atrophic/CRM_2011_Utilities/master/countries_and_states.js) script that will turn the Country field into a dropdown that drives the State/Province field as well.  The State/Province field will be a dropdown for countries that have been configured (by default only USA and Canada, but it’s easy to add your own).  If a country has not been configured, the State/Province field falls back to the default textbox.

More info on how to use it can be found on [on this blog post](http://blog.sincerasolutions.com/post/12003252956/country-and-state-dropdowns-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-20).

Answer (score 1):

The only 'approved' way of having a dynamic control (I think a combo-box describes what you're attempting to achieve) would be to use a Silverlight/HTML Web Resource which could interact with form data through JavaScript.

We've been using a method similar to yours for creating multi-select pick lists (turning text fields into a list of check boxes then storing the result as CSV), however we've come into a problem which you might want to be aware of.

In order for an ISV to have their product available through the [MS CRM Marketplace](http://dynamics.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/home), the product needs to pass an ISV Software Test ([.doc available here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CH4QFjAE&url=http://en-us.lionbridge.com/preliminary-microsoft-dynamics-crm2011-test-guidelines.htm&ei=8ZSqTtfvItCp8AOhqpS7Cw&usg=AFQjCNExUW5I6jy4JUzXjGEyzb1hlUV2sQ&sig2=eRG8ezoBq6vIBm6TXBCG3Q)).  Alteration of the DOM is not permitted by this test:

> Directly modifying the Document Object Model (DOM) of CRM UI
>   components can destabilize the application and/or completely break it.
>
> *How to Comply*
>
> • Do not directly access or modify the Document Object Model (DOM)
>   of any CRM UI component/control.

So we've found we've had to revisit our code to swap out JavaScript DOM fiddling in favour of more heavy-weight, but ultimately more supported, Silverlight controls.

If you've no intention of utilising the marketplace then this doesn't need to effect you, other than to be aware your modifications may not be supported in future updates to CRM.

Comment: We're just doing customizations to a single instance so DOM fiddling will be fine for us (for now, apparently).  We've considered producing some CRM Marketplace solutions though, so this is very useful information, thanks.